# Change column copy their father

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I have problem with persist, in all my `Entities` I have control fields last user was update this and date when he update this. My problem are when I create or update an `Entity` and in this I create or update other `Entity`(dependent) I can´t change 'last user' and 'date update' on generic way. Any idea how to do???

Entity
 contains -> List of dependent Entity
Like
 building -> List of flats

THX and good weekend

Comment: _"Changing dependant entities in generic way_" means the use of `cascade` attribute of the mapping annotation. Show us some code in order to try to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do using Entity Listener that run when @PrePersist event happens, also activate cascade option as Omar said, this will trigger the events over the dependant entities.